# Cannot delete rejected IAP

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

There was a problem with an auto-renewable subscription IAP and Apple rejected it. Now, before submitting the requested non-renewable subscription type, I **have to** delete the old IAPs. But ITC just won't let me (the delete button is disabled). Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you cannot delete renewable subscriptions entirely, just added a new duration with some random product ID and removed the old one with status "Developer Action Needed". Now the IAP will be permanently on "Ready to Submit", but I guess I can live with that.